# Type JSX.Element is not assignable to type React.ReactNode when using customed conditional render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using next: "12.1.6" and react: "18.2.0".

I have a template component for conditional rendering.

```js
// Show.tsx
interface Props {
  when: boolean;
  fallback?: React.ReactNode;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

function Show(props: Props) {
  if (props.when) {
    return props.children;
  }
  return props.fallback ?? null;
}

export default Show;
```

and I use the template component like this but it has an issue.

```
<Show
  when={connectionStatus}
  fallback={
    <div className="border rounded bg-red-400 py-2 px-5">
      ❌ disconnected
    </div>
    }
  >
  <div className="border rounded bg-green-400 py-2 px-5">
    ✅ connected
  </div>
</Show>
```

at the `fallback` attribute, the IDE represents an error "Type JSX.Element is not assignable to type React.ReactNode".

Both `React.ReactElement` and `JSX.Element` is a result of `React.createElement` so I thought there is no specific difference between them except namespace. But it seems `React.ReactNode` cannot cover `JSX.Element`.

What should I update or change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ReactNode` is a ReactElement, a ReactFragment, a string, a number or an array of ReactNode

But in here you are returning an HTML template which is not part of above mentioned categories. Hence you need to change the type to `JSX.Element`

```
fallback?: JSX.Element
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Function to wrap `fallback` JSX Element,

like this :

```
<Show
  when={connectionStatus}
  fallback={() => {
    return <div className="border rounded bg-red-400 py-2 px-5">
      ❌ disconnected
    </div>
    }}
  >
  <div className="border rounded bg-green-400 py-2 px-5">
    ✅ connected
  </div>
</Show>
```

And update `Props interface` to :

```
interface Props extends React.PropsWithChildren<{
  when: boolean;
  fallback?: () => JSX.Element;
}> {}
```